# How could I animate to another screen by using a Material-like circle expanding effect with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

[Here is an example from a mockup I made of what I am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhzj2.jpg)

Right now in code, these are 2 separate screens, but they are simply using a regular built-in animation between screens. Where would I even start to begin achieving an animation like the mockup example? Could I use a Stack that has a circle as a background with a hero tag, and then change its radius? How could I guarantee it would fill the size of any screen?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, you can do it in 1 page, follow this:

1. Layer a full page popup menu widget (let's say the widgets on pink)
   on the page 1 with Stack, hide it at initial.
2. Scale animation to the top left circle when pressing it
3. Show the hidden menu widget after scale animation
4. Hide and reverse the scale animation when pressing closing or back button